# Cannot read property MyToast.java of undefined

Tags: java, android, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have been following this [Tutorial](https://www.codeday.top/2017/10/23/52017.html) to achieve `Write Java code in nativescript and use directly in typescript`

But I got an error `Cannot read property 'MyToast' of undefined`

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
let application = require("application");

declare var org:any;
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {


    public onTap() {
        org.example.MyToast.showToast(application.android.context,"You pressed the button","short");
    }
}
```

I have create **MyToast.java** class in platforms-> src -> java -> org ->example :

```
package org.example;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;


public class MyToast{

    public static void showToast(Context context,String text ,String StrDuration ){

        Toast.makeText(context,text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you perform a build? Metadata for JavaScript->Java invocation will not be generated in a simple `tns run android` where a build has not been triggered.

If you touch `platforms/android`, a build will not be provoked, as that directory is not being watched.

`tns build android` - this will ensure that, when making manual changes in `platforms/android`, a build will be triggered.

Offtopic: Also, I am happy to share that you will be able to create those classes directly in your App_Resources/Android directory in the 4.0 release of NativeScript, without worrying for your custom class being wiped clean when changing workstations, cleaning your project.

Comment: Thank you very much. You made me feel glad today :)

Comment: Always happy to hear that :)